# Creating a edge-trigger symbol in LaTeX

Tags: symbols, tikz-timing

Does anyone know how to create an edge-trigger symbol in LaTeX? I need to to show that some thing activates on the negative clock edge of a signal, but in a paragraph, not in a timing table.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. It'll be helpful to post an image (or a link thereto, since you haven't had image posting privilege yet) of the edge-trigger symbol you referred to.

Comment: I actually just figured it out, but I can't post the answer yet...

Answer (score 7):

The [tikz-timing](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-timing) package.

The `\texttiming{}` macro does the trick! Documentation in above PDF

I used `\texttiming{[-,timing/slope=0]HL}` specifically.

[image]

Comment: a better answer for this exact problem, +1

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a symbol like that, but this can get you started. This solution adapts to the actual line height (`\baselineskip`). So doesn't really matter if you change the font size.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\net{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3\baselineskip/18pt]
 \draw (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand\netp{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3\baselineskip/18pt]
 \draw (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,1) -- (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Negative edge trigger here \net\ and \netp\ and some text after. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just as a small comment. The cleaner way to end a command like this is to use a backslash instead of the tilde. 'Negative edge trigger here \net\ and \netp\' and if you don't want a space after it use {}

Comment: @JohannesO is it a matter of taste or there are diffences in the output?

Comment: A tilde gives you a non breakable space (tie two words together) and should be used in cases when things shouldn't be broken for example Dr.~Mustermann or a Figure~\ref{} that the number of the figure won't end up in the next line. So it is a misuse if you take the tilde to end the command to force a space. Also the space generated by the tilde is not stretchable and a tilde followed by a space would generate two spaces.

Comment: @JohannesO thanks for the heads up. This happens when someone learns LaTeX from codes written by non-experienced users...

Comment: [Essential guide to Latex2e usage](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf) this is a small document with helpful advices for a clean usage of commands and packages. Maybe it is interesting for you. Also avaiable in other languages.

Comment: All `%` but the one after `{` are not necessary, by the way. Instead of *guessing* a proper `scale` value you can directly use font-units `em` and `ex` to draw something that should scale with the text.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel And which one should I use? `em` is a width, and `ex` is a height of a lowercase letter...

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I think `\baselineskip` is exactly the length I should use there. I could've put the `0.3/18pt` in the coordinate fields, but it's better this way.