# How do I make a dashed or dotted checkmark?

Tags: symbols

How do I get a dashed or dotted checkmark in LaTeX (either math mode or text mode is fine).  I'm looking for a symbol approximately like

[image]

Comment: [This topic](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117293/how-to-create-dashed-right-arrow-over-symbol) and [this other one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149254/36821) might help.

Comment: Could you please include a screenshot of what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to use TikZ for that.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\chmdash{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.0012, x=\baselineskip, y=-\baselineskip]
    \fill (228,734) -- (190,638) -- (228,615) -- (242,610) -- (248,623) -- (254,635) -- (266,620) -- (277,604) -- (288,617) -- (305,638) -- (312,648) -- (305,662) -- (292,685) -- (287,697) -- (277,703) -- (239,730) -- (230,738) -- (228,734) -- cycle;
    \fill (166,608) -- (144,592) -- (141,590) -- (161,572) -- (190,558) -- (202,559) -- (216,568) -- (223,582) -- (198,600) -- (172,614) -- (166,608) -- cycle;
    \fill (318,593) -- (299,576) -- (306,563) -- (347,514) -- (353,510) -- (383,534) -- (387,537) -- (373,556) -- (347,592) -- (336,608) -- (318,593) -- cycle;
    \fill (391,496) -- (377,483) -- (452,413) -- (470,435) -- (458,450) -- (415,501) -- (408,508) -- (391,496) -- cycle;
    \fill (482,406) -- (476,396) -- (529,360) -- (538,374) -- (500,407) -- (490,415) -- (482,406) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\raggedright

\small Some text. Some text with \chmdash\ and  \chmdash. Some text. Some text. Some text. \chmdash\ and some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

\Large Some text. Some text with \chmdash\ and \chmdash. Some text. Some text. Some text. \chmdash\ and some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

\end{document}
```

Related: [How to export svg to tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60422/36821)

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution is to use the pdfrender package. Documentation of the package can be found [here](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/pdfrender.pdf). The key is to use the LineDashPattern parameter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\newcommand{\dashcheckmark}{
    \textpdfrender{
        TextRenderingMode=Stroke,
        LineWidth=0.5pt,
        LineDashPattern=[1 1]0,
    }{\checkmark}
}

\begin{document}
    This is a dashed checkmark \dashcheckmark
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can we remove these comments, please? :-) They are not necessary.